# problem with polyglossia after update of MiKTeX 2.9 packages

Tags: errors, miktex, polyglossia

I updated all MiKTeX packages today (2011-10-11) and my files no longer compile. I traced the problem to the `polyglossia` package. Even an empty file won't compile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

gives the following error message:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty"))

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 20, version
               `2011/09/05' of package expl3,
               but only version
               `2011/04/09 v2222 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper'
               is available.

(C:\[..]\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xpackages\xbase\xparse.sty
)
! Argument of \tl_to_str_aux:w has an extra }.
 
                \par 
l.61 \tl_set:Nx \c_colon_str { \tl_to_str:N : }
```

Interestingly, it complains about `calc` and `xparse` packages, but using these two, without `polyglossia`, works OK.

I tried to manually load `xkeyval` before `polyglossia` (as suggested in some other posts), but it does not have any effect.

Any idea how to fix this?

I should probably mention that I run 64-bit version of MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: It was a very bad idea to delete your issue, as I got probably a similar problem and now there is no way to find out!

Comment: I doubt you have the same problem - but if you do, just run update of both Admin and standard packages. (As I said, my problem was that I had been updating only the Admin packages, so all the user-installed packages remained old, so the system became internally inconsistent.)

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, not delete your question. For the record, I'll post your "answer" as a seperate comment.

Comment: From @MichalKaut "I traced the problem to inconsistencies within my MiKTeX installation - I run only the Admin update, so all the on-the-fly installed packages remained old, causing problems.."

Comment: I rolled back the question to the version with the question in it. It's no problem that the problem was on the side of the user -- other users might have the exact same issue. Please add your solution as an answer. As an additional tip: It's usually not necessary to install the multi-user version of MiKTeX, the normal version is much easier to administer and provides the same functionality -- unless you actually need the multi-user functionality. Ulrike Fischer, a MiKTeX-Expert, commented on this topic somewhere, I'll try to find it.

Comment: @doncherry I guess wie rolled back the question more or less at the same time :)

Comment: Here's the comment on the MiKTeX installation: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29616/what-is-preferable-setup-for-miktex/29630#29630

Comment: @Patrick: I don't see a rollback of yours in the edit history, just that you removed `[solved]` from the title. But I don't think it really matters in the end, I'd just like to keep this question on here and open, so I'm hoping there won't be any more close votes.

Comment: @doncherry I did the same as you (the [solved] was another edit) and I was wondering that yours showed up. But this is just a technical remark and I agree with you (with the rollback).