# TeX Live manager 2011 database corruption?

Tags: texlive, luatex, expl3

TeX Live 2011, up to date, on Windows XP. Example:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

LuaTeX first error:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 20, version
           `2011/09/05' of package expl3,
           but only version
           `2011/04/09 v2222 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper'
           is available.

(c:/Programme/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ExplFileName 

l.57 ...e}{\ExplFileVersion}{\ExplFileDescription}
```

---

Ok, but now it get's weird, this output is from console window:

```
U:\>tlmgr version
tlmgr revision 23514 (2011-08-12 23:36:21 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: C:/Programme/texlive/2011
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2011


U:\>tlmgr remove expl3.sty
expl3.sty: package not present, cannot remove
tlmgr: no packages removed.

U:\>kpsewhich expl3.sty
c:/Programme/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/expl3/expl3.sty
```

So TeX Live 2011 is not aware of the fact that the to-be-deleted package still exists. As far as I know, the package and many others have been replaced, see here:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.latex.latex3/2619

Any ideas?

Comment: @CookieJar: So this isn't the same problem you were commenting on earlier this day? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31195/problem-with-polyglossia-after-update-of-miktex-2-9-packages. I rolled back that question for it to remain useful and hopefully open.

Comment: @doncherry Indeed, error messages are similar, but I'm using texlive '11, while there MiKTeX is being used. This hints to a bug deep inside luatex or the l3-packages. On the other hand it is really weird that tlmgr seems not to register a package which is in place and has not been installed by hand!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've experienced this problem. I found my TeXLive had two different expl3.sty-s:

```
<root>\texmf-dist\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
<root>\texmf-dist\tex\latex\expl3\expl3.sty
```

Whether I did this through something silly, or TexLive Manager didn't uninstall the expl3 package at the right moment, I'll never know.

To fix it, I deleted the second of the two files and ran mktexlsr (check which file you're deleting.

Your mileage may vary. Sorry for the Windows path separators.

Comment: YESSS! As this texlive version completly has been maintained by tlmgr, it seems there is a bug. I will report to texlive. But many thanks to Brent, Regards, Alexander