# How do I get expl3 from CTAN?

Tags: siunitx, expl3

My real problem is that I am trying to use a package which depends on `siunitx`, and it complains on compiling with the following error:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
! Package siunitx Error: Support package expl3 too old.. 
See the siunitx package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.29 }
)
```

I would really rather install the package using a package manager. I'm on Gentoo, which has a nice little tool called g-ctan that creates distro packages from packages on CTAN.

`expl3` isn't in the package database, even though it can be [found on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3).

It says that it is a wrapper for experimental LaTeX 3... the package name is `l3kernel`. Eek! Experimental!

Is it safe for me to install `l3kernel`? Is it going to break my LaTeX installation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In common with a number of other Linux distributions, Gentoo probably uses a rather old version of TeX Live (I would assume TL2009, but cannot be sure). You will therefore need to obtain the necessary support files from CTAN and install them locally.

The LaTeX3 support material is currently split into three parts

- [`l3kernel`](http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel.tds.zip)
- [`l3packages`](http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages.tds.zip)
- [`l3experimental`](http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3experimental.tds.zip)

You will need `l3kernel` and `l3packages` to use `siunitx`. The links above are to the ready-to-install TDS-style `.zip` files. Download these, and unzip them inside your local TeX tree (usually `~/texmf`), to create a structure. You should not need to run `texhash` for a local installation, unless Gentoo includes a really old TeX Live or if your `~` folder is not on the 'local' PC.

The 'experimental' nature of the code has been clarified a lot in the past couple of years. The `l3kernel` and `l3packages` code is stable for general use, while `l3experimental` may be more variable. However, none of them will have any impact on other LaTeX material (unless it uses LaTeX3).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if (like me) you put these in the regular TeX tree, the renaming/reorganization of the l3* packages (in 2010 or 2011, I think) required purging the tree of the older files because it led to package clashes.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Take a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31204/tex-live-manager-2011-database-corruption)

Comment: I'm getting a new error after loading these packages: "! LaTeX Error: `cntformats.sty' not found." Anyone encountered this issue. I was just trying to use a new package to make a quick change - that was 2.5h ago. Now I'm losing it! :S

Comment: Don't forget to run `fmtutil-user --all` afterwards for a local update (otherwise use `fmtutil-sys`).

Answer (score 10):

If you are using **MiKTeX 2.9**, try updating it. On Windows:

`Start` > `Miktex 2.9` > `Maintenance (Admin )` > `Update (Admin)`

That solved it for me. I found this suggestions after crawling the web for hours. So, I hope it helps.

Comment: it should (help, that is): `cntformats` is present in current `miktex`; if it doesn’t, ... i dunno.

Comment: It is strange that TeXstudio automatically installs MikTeX packages but fails to update them.

Answer (score 3):

On `Windows` and for the case of `MikTeX`, it is possible that there are two installation: One under the user space and one for all users.

One solution could be that the user deletes all contents at

```
<<DRIVELETTER>>:\Users\<<USERNAME>>\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX
```

and then tries to compile their LaTeX file that will ask to re-installing all required packages.

Comment: This works perfectly for me! Thanks a lot!