# problem with qpxmath: qplri at Xpt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, miktex, font-metrics

I face problems <strike>while using Gyre</strike> with MiKTeX.

The simple example is a template for a journal, downloadable at http://nlp.ipipan.waw.pl/ojs/public/jlm-latex.zip

Following the README file, I installed the packages `tex-gyre`, `qtx` and `qpx`.
I have a problem with the simple example file, characters in math mode are not rendered.

Here is the ME:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{qpxmath}

\begin{document}
$x$
\end{document}
```

actually, the problem is not with the gyre font installation as I first thought, nor with `tgpagella` package, but with `qpxmath` package. `qpxmath` in in TeXLive in `texlive-lang-polish`, but it's quite hard to find for MiKTeX, I'm looking for it right now and I'll post a link here as soon as I find it.

Comment: Make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: In addition to Ulrike: [I've just been told I have to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: thanks, I edited my question, and provided an explanation how to simply reproduce the problem

Comment: @MaximeLefrançois There is no `qplri.tfm` file in the distribution. We need an example of LaTeX code that produces the error, not just the `.log`

Comment: The MWE compiles perfectly on TeX Live 2012

Comment: Yes, but not with MikTeX 2.9, I can't find that qpxmath package...

Comment: In my MiKteX installation it is included. You don’t have a full installation, do you? Go into the package manager and install the package `qpx`. See also [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution).

Comment: Strange... I did install qpx (see the question), both as user and as admin.. Anyways, I installed TexLive and everything is fine now.

Comment: Speravir, I guess you're the closest to the answer, maybe you could post it as an anwer so I vote for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that you have a basic MiKTeX installation: Your MWE works for me with a full installation. Go into the Package Manager and install the package `qpx`. Note, that in the MiKTeX Settings in the `General` tab there is a setting for `Package installation`. If I remember correctly the default setting here for “Install missing packages on-the-fly" is “Ask me first”. You could set it to “Yes” and it will do installations without any asking. The compilation time would once be remarkable longer, of course.

Perhaps you also face some confusion concerning administrative and user mode, see [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex).