# Latex font BrushScriptX and MiKTeX

Tags: fonts, miktex

I am a beginner in Latex. What I know is, how to type my papers. But recently I found out that I can change the fonts of Latex. Perhaps for you is nothing new but for me is really surprising. But there is a problem when I want to use these new fonts which I don't how to fix it. I would be most thankful to you if you could help me to figure out what to do.

I am writing these lines

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pxfonts}

\usepackage{pbsi}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pbsi}

\renewcommand{\mddefault}{xl}

\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{xl}

\usepackage[defaultmathsizes,noasterisk]{mathastext}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}
```

and when I run it I get this:

> Trying to make PK font pbsi8r at 720 DPI... Running
>   miktex-makemf.exe... miktex-makemf: The pbsi8r source file could not
>   be found. Running ttf2pk.exe... miktex-makepk: PK font pbsi8r could
>   not be created. Process exited with error(s)

What does it means?

Comment: The error is not caused by `pxfonts`, but `pbsi`, what is “BrushScriptX-Italic”, and this is missed. It seems to me, that you don’t have a full MiKTeX installation. Another cause could be, that you have forgotten to update the font format files in MiKteX Options. I changed the title. I must also say, that your example works for me (full MiKTeX installation).

Comment: I use MiKTeX package Manager to install missing .sty files. I am really a beginner, so I don't know exactly where is going wrong. But I tried \usepackage{calligra} and this work perfectly.

Comment: Another idaea: Do you have an installation with an admin? Then you must (!) always update the format files in admin _and_ in user mode, cf. also [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex).

Comment: As it stands, this looks 'too localized' to me.

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks, not really an answer, but too long for a comment.

<sup>Hmm, where to begin?</sup>

- Though not very long *(we’ve seen much longer ones)*, your example is not a minimal (not) working example, short MWE. Take a look at [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). By creating one, you probably would have seen by yourself, that your issue is not related to the PX fonts.
- The way you activate the brushscript font is very unusual *). This font is not thought as the main font of a document. According documentation (and source file) one have to use `\bsifamily` for longer text passages and `\textbsi` for shorter parts. For documentation on the Command Prompt do the following `mthelp brushscr`. It should open a html file with links to 3 files. The one to read is the `AAA_readme.dvi`. If that fails, you do not have installed this font. Otherwise a new run of the format file formatter should help. Perhaps you have to do this as admin *and* as user.

  *) *It is not wrong (and especially the `\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{xl}` is good to avoid a warning message). There are a lot of fonts, that are to defined in this or even a more TeX-basic way, for this font it would be `\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pbsi}\fontseries{xl}\fontshape{n}\selectfont`. For more information put a `mthelp fntguide` in the Command Prompt.*

  <sup>For TeX Live users: `mthelp` is the original MiKTeX command. The equivalent in TeX Live is `texdoc` (what in MiKTeX is defined as alias for `mthelp`).</sup>

All together (a `\usepackage{pxfonts}`or another font package could be added anyway):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pbsi}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% only for sample text
\begin{document}

Some short sample text with a \textbsi{short part in BrushScriptX-Italic font},
                             %¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
but most of the sentence in default font face.
\bigskip

\begingroup
%---------
\bsifamily
%---------
\kant[10]
\endgroup

\bigskip

\kant[20]

\end{document}
```

- In `<MiKTeX>\doc\fonts` you can find a lot of documentation for fonts. But in `<MiKTeX>\fonts` are also fonts without documentation. A fine info source is [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).
- For latex in DVI and PDF mode one can only use bitmap and postscript fonts, for the newer truetype and opentype fonts you need the younger developments Xe(La)TeX, Lua(La)TeX and ConTeXt.