# Using garamondx for dummies

Tags: fonts, packages, miktex, texworks

I use TeXworks on Windows to write and produce LaTeX files, which uses MiKTeX in some way I don't fully understant. I've been trying to install and use the `garamondx` package. After a lengthy process I managed to perform what appeared to be an installation of `garamondx` with the MiKTeX Package Manager (the default repository it was using didn't have the package, which took a very long time to figure out), and then the `fontaxes` package when it said it needed it.

When I try to compile a document using the package, though, I get the following error (this is the text that appears at the end of the 'console' on TeXworks; text above that didn't appear to be relevant but I can post it if you want):

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/zgmx/m/scsl' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/zgmx/m/n' instead on input line 27.

[1{C:/Users/win7/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(C:\Users\win7\Desktop\template.aux)Trying to make PK font zgmric8r at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The zgmric8r source file could not be found.

Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font zgmric8r could not be created.


LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file zgmric8r): Font zgmric8r at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
texify: pdflatex failed for some reason (see log file).
```

Googling solutions leads to solutions involving command lines, which (a) I don't understand because I only have a limited understanding of what it is that MiKTeX and TeXworks do respectively (b) I can't implement because I can't find a command line to put them in.

Minimal sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: The errors show that the font is not known to MiKTeX. When you performed the installation with the package maanger I guess you did this as administrator. You should update your filename data base also in user mode then, see also [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that mentioned and have installed `garamondx` in both the vanilla and 'Admin' package managers; the same error message occurs. Unless that's not what you mean?

Comment: Well, your minimal example works for me, so the problem is local on your system. Either the package including the fonts is not installed correctly or the file updating went wrong. So first refresh FNDB.

Comment: What is FNDB and how does one refresh it (cf. "for dummies" above)?

I'm aware it's not a problem with the example and that something isn't present and correct as it should be. I just have no idea what that something could be or how to fix it.

Comment: Run as user in a command line "updmap" to update the pdftex.map. You can find the command line e.g. by right clicking on some folder and holding down the shift key at the same time then you will get the entry in the context menu (in win7) or simply search for cmd.exe.

Comment: Additional links: [How do I update my TeX distribution – MiKTeX GUI](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473) (GUI = Graphical User Interface) or [How do I update my TeX distribution – MiKTeX Command line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55857).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you so much! After all that hassle I ran `updmap` and it worked after about half a second.    

@Speravir Thanks also; I ran this before `updmap`, so I don't know if it contributed to the success (following your advice alone it didn't) but it's useful to know anyway.