# Windows 8, cannot find MiKTeX Options after I unpinned them from Start

Tags: miktex, windows

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 8 and I need to install a package by hand. Looking at their documentation [page](http://docs.miktex.org/faq/maintenance.html#styfiles) I copy my input files to the correct directory and then need to register the new package in MiKTeX Options. The problem, I cannot find MiKTeX Options! When I first installed MiKTeX, MiKTeX Options and some other programs related to MiKTeX showed up on the start screen but I unpinned them and now I cannot seem to find them. Anyone has any ideas? DO I need to re-install MiKTeX maybe?

Comment: If windows 8 has as windows7 a search window then type "settings", this should find the miktex settings. Or go in the windows explorer to the miktex/bin folder and start mo.exe.

Comment: Click on the Windows logo (left bottom) and type `miktex` and then you'll find the MikTeX menu. Use the one with `(adm)` to install packages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer your suggestion to find and start mo.exe did the trick! How do I mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. One cannot accept comments like this as an answer, but if @UlrikeFischer writes an answer then you can accept that.

Comment: @Sigur It depends, cf. [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex).

Comment: This link may help you https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If windows 8 has as windows7 a search window then type "settings", this should find the miktex settings. Or go in the windows explorer to the `miktex/bin` folder and start `mo.exe`.

Comment: I love how THAT is windows answer. How pathetic.