# Missing mathtools package

Tags: packages, windows, mathtools

I am using Windows 8. I have installed MiKTex 2.9 and TeXstudio. However, when I compile the document, the process exits with the following error:

```
File `mathtools.sty' not found. \usepackage
```

When I searched for the solution, it suggested to open the package manager folder in MiKTeX. However, I could not find any folder in the main MiKTeX folder.

I have tried re-installing MiKTex and TeXstudio, but the problem still persists.

I really hope that you can help me and explain in a simple way the mistakes I am doing.

Thank you!

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) Please open the miktex package manager. In one of the menus there is an item called 'synconize', use it, Then find and install the `mathtools` package. Note that `TeXstudio` is *not* related to this.

Comment: Where can I find the package manager?

Comment: Hi Aashay, please have a look at **all** answers in this question, it is a known issue : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199883/problems-installing-mathtools Could you please let us know if that answers your question?

Comment: Ahh, windows 8, it is in the list of programmes somewhere. Not a windows 8 user.

Comment: For windows 8 part look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152669/windows-8-cannot-find-miktex-options-after-i-unpinned-them-from-start

Comment: Thank you @percusse, the link was helpful. It worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure since you used the other questions for the solution I've voted for a duplicate.