# Installing packages with miktex 2.9

Tags: packages, miktex

I tried to install the package `mathalfa` using the package manager (admin), it supposed that clicking on the plus sign everything is done, but when I call the package in my tex file and use the commands that are part of that package, MiKTeX cannot compile it and it tells "undefined control sequence". What I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you by any chance once have used the user update? Because it looks like you need to update the FNDB as user. And you also will have to do this in future for _every_ update the admin does.

Comment: Shouldn't it complain the package isn't found in that case? [Note: I know zilch about MiKTeX.]

Comment: Show a complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem and the log-file of this example. @Speravir: If one use the package manager to install it shouldn't be necessary to update the FNDB. But it is quite possible that the package is already installed in the User root and hides the (newer) admin version. In this case one should run the update manager (as user).

Comment: @lalo See Ulrike’s comment above. And as addition to my first remarks: [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67712).

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because you did not refresh the database.
To refresh the database of the packages, do the following:

1. open MiKTeX options (from your start menu)
2. In the General Tab (click on **refresh FNDB**).
3. Recompile your file, it should work by now.

   - If you are running a portable version of MiKTeX, follow these procedures:

     1. In the Miktex folder, open the file named (miktex-portable.cmd)
     2. In the notification area, there will be a MiKTeX icon, right click on it and then choose MikTeX options.
     3. In the General Tab (click on **refresh FNDB**).
     4. Recompile your file, it should work by now.