# MikTeX unable to find installed ytableau package

Tags: packages, miktex

I want to use `ytableau` package. I was using MikTex 2.8 and after trying to compile I recieved a message that it would not be possible to download packages for MikTex 2.8 any more. So, I have installed MikTex 2.9 with the option of on-the-fly installation assigned and it did not work. MikTex still complains about not having found the package and it does not even try to download it from internet. So I opened the package manager, selected the package and clicked on install (inside task menu). Apparently, it installs the package, but guess what happens when I run LaTeX... It still does not find that package. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I modified the title a bit, to make it more specific for the question, hope that is OK. (If you disagree, you can of course change it again.)

Comment: some related info: [Installing packages with miktex 2.9](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158834/579); this one is overkill, but useful: [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/579)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that, as happens from time to time with MiKTeX packages, it isn't really installed: you have the doc and the source files. So you have to extract the archive, preferably outside of the MiKTeX tree, which will contain a "source" directory with a ytableau-src.tar.bz2. Extract this one ; you'll then get a `source\latex\ytableau` directory that contains two files: ytableau.dtx and `ytableau.ins`.

Compiling ytableau.ins with latex will produce from ytableau.dtx a `ytableau.sty` file. Move it to `\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ytableau\` (or maybe your local TeX root\tex\latex\ytableau\, since it was not installed by the distribution). All that remains to do is to refresh the FNDB.

**Edit:** The bug is fixed with the 2014/2/19 update, cf. bug tracker entry [Package ytableau incomplete](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2304/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you clicked on the "Refresh FNDB" button in the MiKTeX Options application? I always had to do that after installing a new package with MiKTeX 2.8 before it could be found. I have not had to do any manual installs with MiKTeX 2.9 - the "on the fly" option seems to be working OK for me.

What are you using to invoke MiKTeX by the way? I use TeXnicCenter. I am trying to recall if I had to do anything when I upgraded MiKTeX, and I can't think of anything specific, other than changing the path to point to MiKTeX 2.9 in TeXnicCenter, but if I think of anything else I'll post back!

Incidentally, the MikTex Options "Roots" panel suggests that it is searching
`C:\Program Data\MikTex2.9\` and 
`C:\Program Files\MikTex 2.9\` 
but I was searching for my recently installed packages earlier and eventually found them in 
`C:\Users\Fiona\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex`
This might give you somewhere to look to check whether it installed correctly?

Comment: You looked in MiKTeX Settings for Admin first. This does only see these two directories. the other is user specific. See also [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67712).

Comment: Ah, ok. I always use the Admin but I guess thinking about it it's obvious that it wouldn't point to individual user profiles. I also didn't expect it to install packages in a user-related way, but then I don't know much about windows ;-)

Comment: When you really only use admin mode, then I wonder as well.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Incidentally, I just tried running the non-Admin version and it just threw up an error. Reminded me why I have always used the Admin version. We're not all computer experts you know!

Comment: Because the admin mode does not know any of the user directories, it cannot install in of them.

Comment: Hi all. I tried to install it by myself following @Bernard and FionaSmith suggestions, but I wasn't able to mke it work correctly. Thus I have updated the FNDB and formats on settings of maintenance (admin) and the on-the-fly option is working finely now. Thank you everyone who tried to help me.