# Packages not found (Windows 7 TeXmaker)

Tags: packages

I'm using TeXmaker on Windows 7. When I tried to add the `diagbox` and `glossaries` packages in my document and I compiled, it errored and printed:

> !LaTeX Error : File 'glossaries.sty' not found.
> etc ...

Any ideas as to why this is?

Comment: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: @cfr I'm not a native speaker (and I believe you are?), but I'm at least [not the only one](https://ph.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150402080401AAaEtfx) who thinks the phrase "welcome to here" sounds a bit odd `:-P`.

Comment: What the purpose of the post anyway ? :-D

Comment: @Sverre It does. I would prefer to say just Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because you did not refresh the database. To refresh the database of the packages, do the following:

1. open MiKTeX options (from your start menu)
2. In the General Tab (click on refresh FNDB).
3. Recompile your file, it should work by now.

---

- If you are running a portable version of MiKTeX, follow these procedures:

  1. In the Miktex folder, open the file named (miktex-portable.cmd)
  2. In the notification area, there will be a MiKTeX icon, right click on it and then choose MikTeX options.
  3. In the General Tab (click on refresh FNDB).
     Recompile your file, it should work by now.

Refer to my answer at [Installing packages with miktex 2.9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158834/installing-packages-with-miktex-2-9/391670#391670)

Comment: Maybe you should put "Check if the package is installed" at the first place.