# Is there a cross-platform way to acquire the local package installation directory?

Tags: installing, miktex, texlive, mactex, distributions

I'm making a small bundle of 'package-lets' for my classmates and need an easy way to register [my package-lets](http://github.com/vermiculus/playtex) with the local TeX installation.

Only the following distributions will be 'supported':

- MikTeX (via `mpm`)
- MacTeX/TeXLive (via `tlmgr`)

I cannot assume that they will keep their assignments all in the same directory (I can understand the desire to deeply organize things when graphical explorers would shove way too much information in your face), so I *must* register them with the system.

I have [a way to install the packages](https://github.com/vermiculus/playtex/blob/bfb1f45e94b3589193d994172c630dc131a1d5d3/makefile) once I have the path (something like `…/texmf-local/tex/latex/`), assuming `texhash` is cross-platform.

Comment: In TL, `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` will give you the value of the user's texmf home. I would recommend installing there as it avoids the need for `texhash` and can be installed even by users who don't have admin rights on a system. Also, it is easy to tell people how to clean up later if they want to e.g. get rid of your install of `pgf` when their TeX installation gets the new version. (Exception: if you were installing fonts.) Better to use `install` than `cp` on unix-type systems and you can set the mode with `-m`. Plus install into a sub-directory of `tex/latex` for tidiness.

Comment: @cfr It seems that when I ``install package.sty `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` ``, TeX cannot find `package.sty` when I `\usepackage{package}`.

Comment: Well, it needs to be under `tex/latex/pkgname` within TEXMFHOME or latex won't find it. See my suggestion below.

Comment: MiKTeX has a different concept of local root directories. IT does know `kpsewhich -var-value`, but the variable `TEXMFHOME` is empty, and even worse, when upon installation one chose user mode install (as I did) `TEXMFLOCAL` points to the main installation path! Cf. [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67713) and also [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484). For adding a local root the right command would be `initexmf --register-root` (doubling the hyphen is important here, because `-r` is a different swi

Comment: @Speravir This is looking more and more like MikTeX/Windows users are out of luck for now.  Isn't there any tool up on CTAN that simplifies all of this?

Comment: @SeanAllred: Not that I know, but perhaps others have more ideas/more clue. On the other hand _installation_ should be possible with a batch script, when you pack this together with your `sty` files into one file and write a Readme "Extract everything into a temporary folder and execute the batch script …". _Uninstallation_ with a batch script is quite probably harder/not possible unless the whole `playtex` folder could be deleted with included files.

Comment: So you cannot rely on the value of `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL` with MiKTeX, even? (Because you could use that with TeX Live even though TEXMFHOME is more straightforward.)

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work for unix-like systems i.e. OS X, BSDs, GNU/Linux etc.

According to the comments, a variant might work for TeX Live on Windows but not, it seems, for MiKTeX. Being eminently unqualified to do otherwise, I pass over those matters in silence.

```
install -m 755 -d $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/playtex
install -m 644 exam-extensions.sty smcm-danda.sty smcm-math.sty $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex/playtex
unzip -q pgf_3.0.0.tds.zip -d $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)
```

Setting the mode is less important if installing into `TEXMFHOME` rather than `TEXMFLOCAL` but still good practice.

Note that installing your files into a subdirectory of `tex/latex` keeps things tidy and reduces the chances you will inadvertently overwrite an existing file of the same name. To avoid that for certain, you could use `cp -n` and then use `chmod 644` on the `.sty` files.

Comment: This will certainly work wonderfully on UNIX systems, but is there an `install` analog for Windows?  (I can't assume any sort of UNIX environment either; I'll be making a series of `install.bat` files for Windows users to double-click.)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea whatsoever about Windows. The only thing I know for sure is that Windows is not Linux/BSD/GNU etc. I also don't know if MiKTeX has `kpsewhich`. By the way, shouldn't `smcm-danda.sty` use `\RequirePackage` if it is a package? `\ProvidesPackage` is a useful command to include because the information can help in case of debugging etc. Also, I don't know what it does but `\endinput` seems a common finale.

Comment: MikTeX does have `kpsewhich`, thankfully. And it *should*, but I'm still far from any real release.  When I'm ready to distribute my stuff to the class, I'll make them model files.  If I can find an `install` analog for Windows, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: It might be that `copy` on Windows (whatever corresponds to `cp`) is also an analogue for `install`. As I understand it (please correct me), Windows doesn't have the same notion of file modes as Unix-type systems. (Certainly if you use a Fat 32 filesystem, *everything* becomes executable which I find terrifying. But I know Windows now uses more sophisticated filesystems.) Since the main feature of `install` as opposed to `cp` is that it can handle modes, owners, groups etc., I am not sure whether a Windows analogue would make sense?

Comment: You are correct in that Windows doesn't have a concept of file modes, necessarily, but rather more abstract and unnecessarily hard-to-get-at *permissions*.  I am planning on using `copy` at the moment; right now I'm seeing if there is any sort of a 'target' concept in batch files: http://superuser.com/q/717458/160871

Comment: Rather you than me ;). When you solve it, perhaps you should answer your own question? For the Windows part, anyway...

Comment: Sorry, but I have to un-accept given new information in the comments above---apparently `TEXMFHOME` isn't a real thing under MikTeX, which throws a wrench in this general approach.

Comment: @SeanAllred: I really think the true answer to your question is “No.” because of “cross-platform”. But you could provide a ZIP file with make **and** batch scripts (one for MiKTeX, one for Windows TeX Live), so it would be semi cross-platform.