# LaTeX file compiles on two computers but not on the third

Tags: table-of-contents, installing, miktex, auctex

I have tried to troubleshoot a problem for several days and cannot
solve it.

I have a LaTeX document that compiles on two computers but not on a
third computer. (Other documents have compiled fine on the third
computer, which is relatively new.) All three computers have the
MikTeX 2.9 distribution that are all up to date, all use emacs 24.3.1,
AUCTeX 11.86, and Windows 7. I have set MikTeX to download packages on
the fly so I believe that I have identical packages downloaded. My
master document brings in three files via \include. I am reading the
files from a portable HD into all three computers. EDIT: Put
differently, I am compiling the files on all three computers from
files that reside on a single portable HD that I am moving to each
computer.

I cannot figure why the document does not compile on the third
computer. I believe the problem relates to either the table of
contents or section headings of the document because the .toc file is
empty (size = 0) after compiling on this computer.

The error message is:

> ```
> ERROR: Missing control sequence inserted.
> --- TeX said ---
> <inserted text> 
>                \inaccessible
>  l.1 ...m \z@ {[1][-]}\futurelet \@let@token \let [
>                                                      -]{chapter.14}{Economic Da...
> --- HELP ---
> This is probably caused by a \newcommand, \renewcommand, \newlength,
> or \newsavebox > command whose first argument is not a command name.
> ```

The reference to Chapter 14 in the error message is one of the three
files brought in via \include.

I tried going through the log file and see some potential problems but
I cannot interpret them. Attached is the log file and the issues I
observe begin around line 1295. 
EDIT: This portion of the log is at the bottom.

I believe the issue is probably some kind of TeX installation
problem. I hope someone can point me in the right direction because I
am stuck.

Portion of Log:

```
(r:\writing_other\aicpa_forensicaccounting\book_fa_content\fa_wrap.aux
(r:\writing_other\aicpa_forensicaccounting\book_fa_content\fa_damages_content.a
ux
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.11 ... wrong--perhaps a missing \protect \let }}
                                                   } } } } }
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.11 ...rong--perhaps a missing \protect \let }} }
                                                   } } } }
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.11 ...ng--perhaps a missing \protect \let }} } }
                                                   } } }
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.11 ...--perhaps a missing \protect \let }} } } }
                                                   } }
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.11 ...perhaps a missing \protect \let }} } } } }
                                                   }
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.11 ...rhaps a missing \protect \let }} } } } } }

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.14 ...rong--perhaps a missing \protect \let  } }
                                                   }
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.14 ...ng--perhaps a missing \protect \let  } } }

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.17 ...rong--perhaps a missing \protect \let  } }
                                                   }
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.17 ...ng--perhaps a missing \protect \let  } } }

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

))
```

Comment: You can add `\listfiles` at the end of your header, which causes the versions of your used packages to get output to the log. You could compare those, maybe you use an old package on one.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. There's surely a much smaller version document you can attach that shows the same problem. For our purposes, both emacs and AucTeX are irrelevant, only your file content and the MiKTeX files matter.

Comment: @MikeR I don't believe the issue requires a MWE as the problems seems to be related to installation rather than coding.

Comment: So how can we know what the installation status is? Just compile chapter 14 and start moving the `\end{document}` until the error goes away then you can find the offending part.

Comment: @MikeC _every_ question should have an MWE. However delete all the .aux files, especially as the error was generated while reading the aux file.

Comment: @MikeC not to dispute anything percusse or David said, but a file with dozens of chapters isn't something that can be easily fixed remotely, and I'll almost guarantee if David's recommendation doesn't work, that you can cut it down considerably. I had a user spend days here trying to figure out a citation problem with their mountain-sized document, and once I got it down to a 5-line document with the same problem, I only had one error left to google, and it was fixed in 10 minutes.

Comment: Is it _exactly_ the same input file? Could it otherwise be a problem with UTF-BOM?

Comment: @Speravir Yes, it is the SAME input TeX files. They are on a portable HD and I am moving the HD between computers. Not sure how UTF-BOM would creep into this.

Comment: @MikeC: Oooh, and the TeX distribution is portable, too? If not, are you sure you have correctly updated on all three computers? Installation on the fly does install into you user profile and makes an FNDB refresh in user mode, cf. [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67712). Since it’s physically the same file, there can be no difference, whether there is a BOM or not in the beginning of this file. BTW your latest comment is essential information, you should edit his into your question.

Comment: @Speravir Only the TeX files are portable as they reside on a portable HD, and not the TeX distro which are locally installed on each computer. I did a FNDB refresh after reinstalling MiKTeX yet again on the third computer and updating via on-the-fly with no success. Also, I did make the edit to my original post that you suggested.

Comment: @MikeC: And you did refresh in user mode? Then I have no idea anymore. Or. Make a safe copy of this input file and then follow an approach similar to percusse: At the end of chapter 14 add `\endinput`. Compile and move this line step by step to top. Hopefully at some point everything works. Then you must look, what is the causing error.

Comment: @ Juri Robl \listfiles is a brilliant idea. Unfortunately, I cannot get the document to compile and, thus, the list of packages do not appear in my log file.

Comment: Compile (with `\listfiles`) using the option `-file-line-error`; this often helps pin down which line on which file is causing trouble. (I assume this option exists on Windows, but I'm not sure.) And bear in mind that even if it is an 'install' problem, it *is* a (sort of) coding problem because something is calling some bit of the installation that isn't working properly. You need to find the line that is causing this. Also, part of the MWE methodology is to keep narrowing down your file, ideally by halfing the amount included after each unsuccessful attempt. (This shouldn't take many days.)

Comment: @jon: Not in MiKTeX, but in TeX Live for Windows. In MiKTeX one could (only) use `-halt-on-error`, what stops on first occurring error.

Comment: @Speravir -- Oh, too bad.  `-file-line-error` has come  in handy for me for a few large projects with (many) included files...

Comment: @jon: Hmm, this option is not documented for pdflatex, but a user wrote very recently a bug report. (???) See [--file-line-error option produces less detailed report](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2310/).

Comment: @Speravir  -- I cannot reproduce that apparent bug.  Although I use AUCTeX, I do not use that option as part of my setup; rather I run it, when wanted, from the command line.  If I do so, I get exactly the same error in the `.log` at exactly the same place.  More importantly, from the terminal, the default is not to run in non-interactive mode, which means it halts on error and exactly at that error.  Anyway, the advantage of `-file-line-error` is that when you have `\include`-ed or `\input`-ed files, it notes the error for the line *in* the actual included file rather than the masterfile.

Comment: @Speravir -- FYI.  I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with TL 2013, updated a few days ago.

Comment: Add `\listfiles` to your document and add `\end{document}` directly after `\begin{document}`. Delete the .aux-files. Then you will probably be able to compile and get the file list. Also Speravir wrote about an user *update* (with the update manager) not simply a FNDB refresh (which is quite senseless as all files are found).

Comment: @jon: I was misinterpretative: This option is not documented for latex in MiKTeX, but the user reported a bug in MiKTeX using this option.

Comment: @MikeC: Oh, yes, Ulrike is right: I wrote only about refreshment, but if you install packages on the flight then they are only in you user folders and you _must_ update as user and refresh as user (but when you update with GUI, the update is done automatically).

Comment: @Ulrike Your approach led me to the solution. Running `\listfiles` on both computers allowed me to identify MikTeX packages on each computer and then I diffed the two listings. My problem ended up being the pgf files. I ended up rolling back to the older pgf files that were on the computer that compiled the document successfully.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a too localized bug.