# miktex slow compile

Tags: pdftex, miktex, pandoc, markdown, sublime-text

I have written a build system in sublime text 3 to build markdown files and convert them to pdf.

my system is:

- OS: Windows 10
- MiKTeX version: MiKTeX 20.12
- pdflatex version:  MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.1

To build a md file with one word ("test") it takes 17.5 seconds inside sublime text.

I have done some profiling with the powershell using the [eisvogel template:](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/blob/master/eisvogel.tex)

1. conversion md to tex with pandoc: 0.0907997 [s]
2. conversion: tex to pdf with pdflatex: 6.3132436 [s]
3. conversion md to pdf with pandoc: 13.2551959 [s]

If I run 1 and 2 in sublime text 3 the process lasts ca. 8 seconds and the console prints this:

```
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 3
L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03>
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scra
rtcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script document class (article)

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrk
base.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrb
ase.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrl
file.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrl
file-hook.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrl
ogo.sty))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty")))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\tocb
asic.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\scrs
ize11pt.clo)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/koma-script\type
area.sty)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\lmodern.sty")
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/setspace\setspac
e.sty) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/lm\t1lmr.fd"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty")
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/upquote\upquote.
sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microt
ype.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microt
ype-pdftex.def)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microt
ype.cfg)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def")
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/colortbl\colortb
l.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/latex-tools\arra
y.sty)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\dvipsnam.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\svgnam.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\x11nam.def"))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xurl\xurl.sty
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty"))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/bookmark\bookmar
k.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmd
s.sty) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty"
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infw
arerr.sty))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvse
tkeys.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\k
vdefinekeys.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfe
scape.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.
sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letl
txmacro.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.
sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvopti
ons.sty) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def")
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intcal
c.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexc
mds.sty) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def")
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.
sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\big
intcalc.sty)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty")
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\r
erunfilecheck.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/uniquecounter\
uniquecounter.sty)))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/bookmark\bkm-pdf
tex.def))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometr
y.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty")
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometr
y.cfg))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/footnotebackref\
footnotebackref.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/float\float.sty)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\babel.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def"))
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/babel-english\english.ldf"))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/csquotes\csquote
s.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/csquotes\csquote
s.def)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/csquotes\csquote
s.cfg))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption.
sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption3
.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/caption\caption-
koma.sto)))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mdframed\mdframe
d.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse-generic.tex"))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/zref\zref-abspag
e.sty
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/zref\zref-base.s
ty))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/needspace\needsp
ace.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/mdframed\md-fram
e-0.mdf))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/sourcesanspro\so
urcesanspro.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ly1\ly1enc.def
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ly1enc.dfu"))))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/sourcecodepro\so
urcecodepro.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty"
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/sourcesanspro\t1
sourcesanspro-tlf.fd)))
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/titling\titling.
sty)

Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of package `fancyhdr' together
(scrartcl)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrartcl)              I'd suggest to use 
(scrartcl)              package `scrlayer' or `scrlayer-scrpage', because
(scrartcl)              they support KOMA-Script classes.
(scrartcl)              With `fancyhdr' several features of class `scrartcl'
(scrartcl)              like options `headsepline', `footsepline' or command
(scrartcl)              `\MakeMarkcase' and the commands `\setkomafont' and
(scrartcl)              `\addtokomafont' for the page style elements need
(scrartcl)              explicite user intervention to work.
(scrartcl)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrartcl)              package `fancyhdr' on input line 248.


(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhd
r.sty) (test.aux)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ly1\ly1ptm.fd)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty"
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/refcount\refcoun
t.sty)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/generic/gettitlestring
\gettitlestring.sty))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
[1{C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
 (test.aux) ){C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/fonts/enc/dvi
ps/sourcesanspro/a_emkxm5.enc}<C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/MiK
TeX/fonts/type1/adobe/sourcesanspro/SourceSansPro-Regular.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 53720 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

With the same build system on a macbook pro (M1 processor, late 2020, texlive installed), the process with pandoc from md to pdf lasts less than 2 seconds.

Do you have any idea why miktex is ~3 times slower than texlive?

Comment: If your processing pipeline has to access many files, then this may be an explanation: Windows often proves significantly slower in accessing the file system than Linux or Unix-type operating systems. I don't think that it is a MiKTeX vs. TeXlive issue.

Comment: It may not be relevant to the timing (but it may) but your log shows a classic miktex issue of a mixture of admin and user mode installs, some of your files coming from `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex` and some from `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex` if you update the system in both user and admin mode you will get consistent paths

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's reeaaaally interesting. How could I update the system? Uninstall and re-install. I think you got the point.

Comment: I don't use miktex but (from saying this 10000 times on this site) going to the miktex console and updating in user and admin mode fixes many issues.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling and installing miktex in user-only mode. There is a speed gain, i.e. compiling is ~10% faster.
I found some helpful information about this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex) (see Speravir answer!)

Comment: @gernot for that to have any appreciable difference, you'd need to have *thousands* of files