# Starting with LaTeX. Immidiately get an error

Tags: errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [the memory dump file could not be found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81739/the-memory-dump-file-could-not-be-found)

Just trying to get started here with LaTeX, but I immediately get this strange error. I'm not much of a computer scientist to understand what I need to do next. Tried some Google searches but that was not of much help to me. Do you guys know what to do?

The error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
pdflatex.exe: The memory dump file could not be found.
pdflatex.exe: Data: pdflatex.fmt
```

I was typing some basic stuff, and then pressing the green 'play' button. It seems to me that he has trouble finding the `pdflatex.exe`?

For extra information:

```
Using MiKTeX version 2.9 and TeXworks version 0.4.4.1003
```

[image: problem]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Possible duplicates: [error: pdflatex.exe: the memory dump file could not be found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36543), [the memory dump file could not be found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81739)

Comment: Thank you Claudio Fiandrino. The answer was in the 'rights' of the user.

When i close TeXworks and reopen by right clicking and then selecting: "Run as administrator" then the error is gone and it works like a charm.