# Using "◌" in Latex - "Unicode char \u8:Γùî not set up for use with LaTeX"

Tags: symbols, unicode

How can I use the character `◌` (`25CC`): http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cc/index.htm ?

I am using MikTex (pdflatex) under Window; I am importing the following packages:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

When pasting the character into my document, I receive the following error message:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:Γùî not set up for use with
>   LaTeX.

I read about using `utf8x` instead of `utf8`, but this package is incompatible to `biblatex`.

How can I solve this one?

EDIT: Thanks for all the responses and the various ways to draw circles! I should have mentioned that I need the circle to be combined with diacritic marks (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_circle ) - the result then looks like this:

## ◌̊

Thus, the XeLaTeX seems to be the way to go in my case.

Comment: Is using XeLaTeX an option?

Comment: First of all, you need to find a TeX font that has the glyph.

Comment: @doncherry: I was trying to avoid switch the latex processor because I fear other incompatibilities. I am currently trying it out and already ran into this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36543/error-pdflatex-exe-the-memory-dump-file-could-not-be-found (a path without spaces seems to have fixed it).
egreg: Arial has it (displays fine in Word).

Comment: @doncherry: XeLaTeX fails on the letter 'ü' with error message: "Keyboard character used is undefined in inputencoding 'utf-8'". So much for Unicode-support.

Comment: @winSharp93 Did you use `\usepackage{fontspec}` and remove `inputenc` and `fontenc`? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex.

Comment: @egreg I posted an answer based on your comment. Is that ok? :D

Comment: @doncherry: Thanks, that did the trick! So far, the result looks very promising.

Comment: If you want to stick with pdflatex the stix-beta distribution is packaged for classic tex and includes `\dottedcircle`

Comment: See also my edit: Because I need to combine the circle, the graphic solutions are nice, but not ideal in my case. I'll go with XeLaTeX. Thanks again for all your ideas and answers!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could set your font to one that supports Unicode (this solution requires XeLaTeX):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS} % Other fonts that might work: Hiragino Maru Gothic Pro, Lao Sangam MN, Inaimathi, Microsoft Sans Serif

\begin{document}\huge

\noindent a b c \\
◌ \\
ä ë \\
à è \\
ç 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This only works in XeLaTeX, right?

Comment: @winSharp93 No I use pdflatex. :)

Comment: erh, `fontspec` requires `xelatex` or `lualatex`

Comment: As for CTAN fonts, DejaVu Sans and DejaVu Serif  contain this glyph, too.

Comment: @daleif The Default engine I use is pdflatex. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAzG9.png).

Comment: That document does not work in pdftex, what does your log say at the top?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is this what you meant? If yes, then you guys are right, it's XeLaTeX: `This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013) (format=xelatex 2013.9.28)  15 OCT 2013 15:18`

Comment: @Alenanno yes:-)

Answer (score 16):

You can prepare the following file `dottedcircle.tex`

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\begin{document}
^^^^25cc
\end{document}
```

and compile it with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Choose a font you have on your system and has the glyph.

Then you can use the PDF in your `pdflatex` documents with this strategy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{◌}{\includegraphics{dottedcircle}}

\begin{document}
a b c ◌ ä ë
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have the Stix fonts installed, you can use them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LS1}{stixscr}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stixscr}{m}{n} {<->s*[.7] stix-mathscr}{}

\newunicodechar{◌}{{\usefont{LS1}{stixscr}{m}{n}\symbol{\string"E3}}}


\begin{document}
a b c ◌ ä ë
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This uses the `stackengine` package to construct the glyph from `\circ`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\dottedcirc{\color{white}%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.4pt}{--}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.5pt}{--}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.1pt}{\rotatebox{90}{$-$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.1pt}{\rotatebox{45}{$-$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.1pt}{\rotatebox{-45}{$-$}}{%
\textcolor{black}{$\circ$}%
}%
}}}}\color{black}}
\begin{document}
x\dottedcirc y
\end{document}
```

[image]

I EDITED the solution when I found that a lower-case `o` immediately preceding the `\dottedcirc` was slightly overlapped.  Here I use two slightly overlapped n-dashes (`--`) in lieu of a minus sign (`$-$`) for the horizontal whiteout stroke.

If you substitute `red` for `white`, you can see how the stack is formed:

[image]

Based on comment from OP, I cannot easily make the dashed circle dotted in the sense of using small circles around the perimeter.  However, I can subdivide the sircle more frequently with smaller dashes, giving a similar appearance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\dottedcirc{\color{white}%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.4pt}{--}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{-.5pt}{--}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.2pt}{\rotatebox{90}{$-$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.2pt}{\rotatebox{30}{$-$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.2pt}{\rotatebox{60}{$-$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.2pt}{\rotatebox{-30}{$-$}}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{.2pt}{\rotatebox{-60}{$-$}}{%
\textcolor{black}{$\circ$}%
}%
}}}}}}\color{black}}
\begin{document}
x\dottedcirc y
\end{document}
```

[image]

which, blown up, is

[image]

---

Look for V3.21 of `stackengine` to be propagated in the coming days, to fix a bug associated with `\stackinset`, when using `l` or `r` horizontal justification.

Comment: Thanks for the effort; but this produces a dashed circle which is slightly different from the dotted one. I really would like to have the actual character.

Comment: @winSharp93 Your pointed-to website http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cc/index.htm shows it as dashed.  But I appreciate your needs may vary

Comment: Wikipedia has it with dots: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_circle - so it is font dependent. Nevertheless, it's always nice to see what's possible with LaTeX, so thanks again for your input :-)

Answer (score 9):

*Sigh* Someone's got to do it: If you don't mind loading a full-fledged graphics framework for the job, you can of course use TikZ (using the approach from [Dotted lines in TikZ with round dots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101262/dotted-lines-in-tikz-with-round-dots) to get round dots):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\dottedcircle{\tikz \draw [line cap=round, line width=0.25ex, dash pattern=on 0pt off 2pt] (0,0) circle [radius=0.75ex];}

\begin{document}
A dotted circle: \dottedcircle
\end{document}
```

Same result can be obtained via low-level PGF commands

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand\dottedcircle{%
\begin{pgfpicture}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.25ex}
\pgfsetroundcap
\pgfsetdash{{0cm}{2pt}{0cm}{2pt}}{0cm}
\pgfcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{0.75ex}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfsetbaseline{-0.75ex}
\end{pgfpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
A dotted circle: \dottedcircle
\end{document}
```

or for the adventurous ones with pure pdf specials (not recommended, just for fun, random size it will give a bigger circle)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A dotted circle: 
\pdfliteral{1 0 0 1 10 10 cm 1 J [0 2] 0 d 1 w  0 -10 m 9 -10 10 0 v 10 9 0 10 v -9 10 -10 0 v -10 -9 0 -10 v S }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey what's wrong with the good ol' PGF ? :P

Comment: @percusse: *chanting* Do it! Do it!

Comment: *googled chant and did it* :P

Comment: @percusse: Woah! Getting close to http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: @percusse: ooh an heretic command! `:)`

Answer (score 8):

This is my 2nd answer, which is a different approach than the other, and driven by the OP's request to use dots rather than dashes.  Here, I use the `fp` package to build up a series of scaled dots into a circle.  There are four settable parameters for the code, including: degree separation of dots around unit circle, radius of circle in ex's, size of dots relative to a period, and overall character width in terms of circle radius.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\usestackanchor{T}%
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcounter{index}
\def\dtheta{30}% degrees per dot
\def\dR{.42}% radius of circle in ex's
\def\dotsize{.6}% size of dots relative to period
\def\charwidth{3}% overall characterwidth in circle radii
\newlength\dRlen
\setlength\dRlen{\dR ex}
\def\basechar{\strut%
  \rule[.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox]{\charwidth\dRlen}{0ex}}
\savestack{\dotcircle}{\basechar}
\setcounter{index}{0}
\whiledo{\theindex<360}{%
  \FPdiv\thetaRad{\theindex}{57.29578}%
  \FPcos\dx{\thetaRad}%
  \FPmul\dx{\dR}{\dx}%
  \FPsin\dy{\thetaRad}%
  \FPmul\dy{\dR}{\dy}%
  \savestack{\dotcircle}{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{\dy ex}{%
    \kern\dx ex\kern\dx ex\scalebox{\dotsize}{.}}{\dotcircle}}
  \addtocounter{index}{\dtheta}%
}
\begin{document}
x\dotcircle y
\end{document}
```

[image]