# Looking for ways to test automatically my homemade packages

Tags: package-writing

In classical programing language like Python, C or JAVA there are tools to do tests.

What are the recommandantions or receipes you use to test your packages ?

Comment: latex itself and a number of packages use l3build.

Comment: Is there some documents explaining the processes to follow ?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46142/how-can-i-automate-regression-testing-for-latex-documents-when-updating-packa

Comment: On how to use `l3build`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329743/example-for-test-files-using-l3build

Comment: Thanks for all.