# biber + WinEdt references not printing

Tags: biber

I'm having difficulty with references printing using WinEdt + biber.  The problem looks just like this post: http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/forums/forum/824416/topic/5413419

Unfortunately, when I re-install MikTEx the problem doesn't go away.  I deleted the cache (if the cache is all the files in the folder besides the tex file) and re-installed MikTex and the problem persists.

Specifically the problem is that references are being placed in the pdf intext but no bibliography prints at the end.

I ran this script:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{kastenholz}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{sigfridsson}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

And here's the console output:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/CONSOLE_OUTPUT.txt

Here's the entire file I ran:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61803503/TEST_BIBER.zip

I don't think wWinEdt has anything to do with this.  Using windows 7 machine with MikTex 2.9

Comment: Looks like you have broken version of biblatex installed in your local tree here: `C:\Users\trinker\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9`. Your attempts to update/reinstall MiKTeX are probably updating only your main tree here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9`.

Comment: This sounds promising, though a right click properties says it was created today.  I found the biber file you discussed.  How do I replace it if deleting MikTex and reinstalling doesn't do it?

Comment: @TylerRinker OK. My guess was wrong, then. You can delete your local tree. Reinstall isn't necessary - just run the update manager as administrator.

Comment: I think I love Audrey and Kurt.  I updated yesterday but had another issue so the problem persisted.  Then when I reinstalled MikTex it needed to be updated still.  That works yay!!!!!

Comment: @TylerRinker: It should not be necessary to deinstall/reinstall everything. But if you have a multiuser installation then you should always run the update manager in user mode *and* admin mode so that packages installed as user *and* packages installed as admin gets updated. (You can also install miktex in your user account "only for you". Then this double update is not needed.)

Comment: When using MiKTeX defaults everywhere, you will end up with `biber` in the admin tree and `biblatex` in the user tree. That way, updating only one of the two trees will at some point lead to the problems described in the question. In my opinion, including `biblatex` in the admin tree in a default installation would be a good decision for future MiKTeX versions.

Comment: related, maybe even duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in your file `test-biber.blg` that you are using `biber 0.9` (line 1: `[0] Config.pm:300> INFO - This is Biber 0.9.9`).

You need `biber 1.0` to run your version of `biblatex`. If you have installed MikTeX new does this not mean that all packages are up to date. Update your MiKTeX system using the administrators Update manager of MiKTeX.