# Biber/BibLaTaX problem: no such file or directory in cache

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber

I am having a problem using biber/biblatex, that I just can't seem to solve. The first problem was Biber complaining about finding the wrong version of biblatex control file (2.6 instead of 2.5), which I tried to fix by installing the latest biber (1.9) [as suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159128/biber-biblatex-getting-errors-when-more-than-one-citation).

Now however, the following error occurs:

```
    read_file 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-7363686d6964746b\cache-c38a9b05b97a81d339b4947ba00f0aacefe00497\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml'
    - sysopen: No such file or directory at  C:\Users\usermane\AppData\Local\Temp\par-7363686d6964746b\cache-c38a9b05b97a81d339b4947ba00f0aacefe00497\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 112.

INFO - This is Biber 1.9 INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
```

What to do??
Is it the same problem as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file)??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Delete the cache folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-7363686d6964746b` and try again.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: If the answer below solves the problem then it should be marked as "answered".

Answer (score 9):

Deleting the temp folder C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\par-7363686d6964746b, as mentioned in comments, worked for me fine.