# How to use Biber with BibLaTeX from the command line

Tags: biblatex, biber

After receiving the suggestion to switch to using Biber in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268424/how-to-diagnose-biblatex-issue), I am now giving it a try. Unfortunately, I seem to invariably end up with the messages

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'History' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 14.
```

and then, a few lines further:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

(Obviously, I have followed that advice at first, but unlike with BibTeX, where two or so reruns would usually suffice, I have gone through the last two lines of the cycle

```
pdflatex test.tex
biber test
pdflatex test.tex
```

**six times** in a row now, and the above message still keeps appearing.

The `.blg` file contains only one warning (that I do not know how to influence, as I am working on a freshly installed unmodified [MikTeX](http://www.miktex.org/) 2.9.5736 x64):

```
[0] Config.pm:324> INFO - This is Biber 2.1
[1] Config.pm:327> INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
[136] biber-MSWIN:273> INFO - === %a %b %e, %Y, %H:%M:%S
[137] Biber.pm:333> INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
[779] Utils.pm:146> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.6, expected version 2.7
[780] Biber.pm:642> INFO - Using all citekeys in bib section 0
[832] Biber.pm:2977> INFO - Processing section 0
[894] Biber.pm:3115> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'test.bib' for section 0
[912] bibtex.pm:1021> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
[921] bibtex.pm:895> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'test.bib'
[1028] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale '' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
[1028] UCollate.pm:66> INFO - Overriding locale '' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
[1029] Biber.pm:2854> INFO - Sorting list 'anyt' of type 'entry' with scheme 'anyt' and locale ''
[1030] Biber.pm:2858> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale ''
[1030] Biber.pm:2858> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale ''
```

As the other messages are all just information messages, no warnings, and no errors, I presume that everything has gone well here.

---

**Minimal working example:**

This is the file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

abc~\cite{History}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the file `test.bib`:

```
@ARTICLE{History,
  author = {Aaron Aman and Betty Beertent},
  title = {A new history of things},
  journal = {Stuff},
  year = {2014},
  volume = {29},
  pages = {3--36},
  timestamp = {2015.09.20}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Happy,
  author = {Charles C. Cooper and Dora D. Davis and Evgeny Eroshkin},
  title = {We are a happy team of researchers},
  booktitle = {Declarations of Confidence},
  year = {2009},
  timestamp = {2015.09.20}
}
```

The resulting PDF file contains only one page with the following content:

[image: abc [History ]]

---

I have found various resources that all imply doing the reruns as I used to with BibTeX should be all that is needed, for instance:

- [This forum thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=23433) suggests "After running biber, you have to do one ore two pdflatex runs again."
- [This LaTeX SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13513/18853) says a simple sequence of *LaTeX - Biber - LaTeX* should do.
- So does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153652/18853).
- [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34136/18853) even specifically mentions `pdflatex` in "To compile you should now call `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`."

---

**How can I get Biber to work as a backend for BibLaTeX?**

Comment: The Hanover sever is up to date according to the MikTeX page. Try the graphical interface for updating. Please see [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864) and [Which one to choose? Update (Admin) or Update, Settings (Admin) or Settings?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179671/35864).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper After a new install the packages included in the installation will be the up-to-date versions at the time of packing the installer. That is why the MikTeX download page says "When you have installed MiKTeX, it is recommended that you run the update wizard in order to get the latest updates."

Comment: @moewe: I see. I misinterpreted "basic TeX/LaTeX system (...) has the ability to install needed packages automatically (on-the-fly)" from the [MikTeX downloads page](http://www.miktex.org/download) as meaning "no packages are included, as whichever package is needed will be installed on-the-fly".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Some are included, I don't know which and I don't know about a list of some sort that holds those packages automatically installed. You should also make sure not to install any packages (or auxiliary programmes such as Biber) manually (as opposed to via the on-the-fly system of the Package Manager) unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: ... In short, rest assured that I will also upvote your answer as soon as it helps me solve this particular problem again, just as I do whenever something already posted to an SE site helps me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is named in this line in your `.blg` file:

```
[779] Utils.pm:146> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.6,
      expected version 2.7 you have biblatex, version, but you need version 2.7.
```

`Biber` and `biblatex` depends on each other. That means a special `Biber` version needs a special `biblatex` version to run. This message comes up if only one part of `biber` and `biblatex` is updated, not both.

That's the reason I asked you: Have you only installed MikTeX? Please run the MiKTeX package manager and install all updateable packages.

A new installed MiKTeX is based of the database for the installer program.  Later changes of MiKTeX packages are not known by the installer program.  That's the reason the best way to install a new MiKTeX version is:

1. run the MiKTeX installer (I personaly prefer the complete net installer, but that is your choice, of course),
2. reboot after finishing installing (Windows: sure is sure)
3. run MikteX package manager to check for new packages (since the installer was build) and install them. I would reboot again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  your problem is the following (I've just had it with your files):

Biber uses a cache file, to be found in `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4265726e617264\` (the numbers may be different), and for some reason, this cache gets corrupted.

The solution consists in deleting this directory. Biber will make a brand new cache at the next run.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not get around to trying this, as an update as described in the comments brought my system to a state at which the described issue does not arise. Hence, I cannot make any statements on the helpfulness of this answer. Please leave your answer around, maybe future visitors find it helpful and will update, though.