# Using Biber with MiKTeX from command line

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, miktex, windows

I am trying to set up Notepad++ on Windows so that I can compile LaTeX documents from it, using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43984/using-notepad-with-miktex-on-windows) excellent solution, using a batch file to compile my documents.
However, the example given uses `bibtex` while I prefer to use `biber`.

I tried simply replacing all references to `bibtex` in the batch file with `biber`, but upon compiling I get errors such as

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 19.

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(main)                main
(main)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

The document compiles correctly apart from the bibliography, which is not found and does not compile.
I know the problem must lie with the batch file, as my MWE compiles fine with TeXStudio and by compiling manually via `cmd` using the commands

```
cd [path to directory]
pdflatex main.tex
biber main
pdflatex main.tex
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{A Minimum Working Example}
\date{}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

    \section{Citing a Thing}
        \cite{QuackQuack}

    \printbibliography[heading = bibintoc]
    \nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

bibliography:

```
@article{QuackQuack,
   author = {A. Author},
   title = {Quack quack quack},
   journaltitle = {Journal of Ducks},
   volume = {1},
   pages = {1},
   year = {2016}
}
```

batch file:

```
::I don't know what the next line does
%~d1
::sets working directory
cd %1
::calls pdflatex and biber on my file
pdflatex %2  
biber %2
pdflatex %2
pdflatex %2
::opens/refreshes the pdf in SumatraPDF
START "" "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %3 -reuse-instance
```

I have checked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268463/how-to-use-biber-with-biblatex-from-the-command-line) question, and have made sure my MiKTeX installation and all packages are up-to-date

I can't find any other solutions to my problem online, and this problem stumps everyone I have asked - any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your batch script calls `bibtex` not `biber`!

Comment: @josephwright - I know it does, this is the _original_ batch file. I modified it to call biber and got the errors detailed in the question

Comment: Can you run Biber from the command line directly? What does `biber --version` give? If you edit your script and replace all `bibtex`s with `biber` what exactly is the problem? Do you get a `.blg` file? What does it say?

Comment: @moewe biber v2.7, biblatex v3.7. I can run `biber` from command line manually and it works fine, references generate perfectly, including being added to contents. I cannot see any `.blg` files being generated

Comment: If you don't get a `.blg` that means that your script failed to run Biber. Is there some way you can check that the script actually runs the commands it claims to run?

Comment: @moewe In `nppexec`s console output, I get `INFO - This is Biber 2.7
INFO - Logfile is 'main.tex.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'main.tex.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
INFO - ERRORS: 1` I checked the file directory, and while there isn't a main.tex.bcf there is a main.bcf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem:

The batch script I was running took three parameters-

`"$CURRENT_DIRECTORY"`, represented in the script as `%1`,

`"$(NAME_PART).tex"`, represented by `%2` and

`"$(NAME_PART).pdf"`, represented by `%3`

This was passing the parameter "main.tex" to `biber`, which was causing the issue to appear. I edited the script to take 4 parameters, now `%3` is passed `"$NAME_PART"`, this is now given to biber, and `%4` is now passed the value that was previously passed to `%3`

The amended script now reads:

```
%~d1  
cd %1
pdflatex %2  
biber %3
pdflatex %2
START "" "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %4 -reuse-instance
```

This successfully compiles the bibliography and all references.
I conclude that biber does not like being given a filename with the `.tex` extension, and prefers instead to simply be given the filename without extension