# How get multiple indexes with arara?

Tags: arara, makeindex

How do I have to change the `arara` commands in the following so that the index of names will also be printed? As it stands, I get just the main index.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: { overwrite: false, output: outputfile.tex, trace: true }

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\makeindex
\makeindex[names]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Area} \label{chap:area}
\section{Area of a circle} \label{sec:circle-area}

Consult \textcite{Archimedes200} and \textcite{EulerE1776}.
\index[names]{Archimedes}
\index[names]{Euler, Leonhard}

The area $A$ 
\nomenclature{$A$}{area}%
of a circle with radius $r$
\nomenclature{$r$}{radius of circle}%
is defined as
\begin{equation}
    A = \pi r^{2}.
\end{equation}
\index{area!of circle}
\index{area}
\index{circle!area of}

\printbibliography

\printnomenclature

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index of Names}
\printindex[names]

\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Here is the file `mybib.bib`:

```
@article{Archimedes200,
  author = {Archimedes},
  title = {Pi's the limit},
  journal = {Syracuse J. Gastronom.\ Math.}, 
  year = {200BCE},
  volume = {10},
  pages={\textsc{CCCXV}--\textsc{CCCXIV}}
}
@article{EulerE1776,
  author = {Euler, Leonhard},
  title = {All about E},
  journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},
  year = {1776},
  volume = {4},
  pages={1--2718}
}
```

Comment: Somebody had posted an answer, involving a modification of makeindex.yaml, that seems to work. But for reasons unknown to me, that answer has been deleted.

Comment: Phelype has written a very interesting approach! I mentioned to him that `arara` has a built-in way of doing this task, and for some reason, he decided to delete it. I will poke him to undelete the answer and add an addendum to the quick way of doing it. `:)`

Comment: By the way, add `% arara: makeindex: { files: [ names ] }` and have fun. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credits to Paulo, for showing me this: all `arara` rules have an implicit parameter called `files`, which takes a (comma-separated) list of file names. `arara` will then iterate in this list and apply that directive to each item in the list.

Another point is that you don't need the two pdfLaTeX runs between BibTeX and MakeIndex: the first run of pdfLaTeX is enough to generate the auxiliary files for the external tools. The final two runs of pdfLaTeX are necessary to include the generated bibliographies/indexes and sort out cross references.

Your list of directives could be changed to:

```latex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: makeindex: { files: [ names ] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

and perhaps replace the two `makeindex` lines by only one (supposing your main `.tex` file is `main.tex`): `% arara: makeindex: { files: [ main, names ] }`.

Or, if you want `arara` to be clever and skip unnecessary steps (explanation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489636/134574)):

```latex
% arara: pdflatex: { draft: yes }
% arara: bibtex if changed (toFile('mybib.bib'))
% arara: --> || found ('log', 'Warning: Citation')
% arara: makeindex: { files: [ main, names ] } if changed ('idx')
% arara: pdflatex until !found('log', '\\(?(R|r)e\\)?run (to get|LaTeX)')
```

---

Another option, as barbarabeeton mentioned in the comment, is the `imakeidx` package, which runs `makeindex` from within pdfLaTeX. Since `makeindex` is a trusted program, it is allowed to run in restricted shell-escape, which is usually enabled. The `imakeidx` package already takes care of multiple indexes and everything.

To use it you would just need to load it with `\usepackage{makeindex}`, and repalce `\makeindex[names]` by `\makeindex[name=names]`.

However the `repeatindex` package you use seems to be incompatible with `imakeidx`... I'll try to figure out why.

---

Or, if you prefer to look like the cool kid (like me, who did all this before being told of the `files` parameter :-) and do it the hard way, you can make a small modification to the `makeindex.yaml` file and add a `basename` option which takes the base name of the index file (`names`, in your case) and works on it instead of the current file name.

First, below the `arguments:` line in `makeindex.yaml` you add the option itself:

```
- identifier: basename
  flag: >
    @{
      parameters.basename
    }
```

(apparently Java doesn't like if you use only `base`, for some reason, so I used the more verbose `basename`.) We set this option without a default value, so that when it's empty we use `getBasename(file)`.

Now we modify the `command:` section to use that option:

```
  command: >
    @{
        if (isEmpty(basename))
          { basename = getBasename(file); }
        infile = basename.concat('.').concat(input);
        outfile = [ '-o', basename.concat('.').concat(output) ];
        logfile = [ '-t', basename.concat('.').concat(log) ];
        return getCommand('makeindex', german, style, order, options,
                          logfile, infile, outfile);
    }
```

first we check if `basename` is empty; if it is, use the current file name from `getBasename(file)`. Then proceed normally adding the extensions of the input, output, and log files, and then calling the `makeindex` executable.

(complete modified version of `makeindex.yaml` file at the bottom of this answer, for your convenience)

After that, you can change your directives to:

```latex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: makeindex: { basename: names }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

(note that I removed the two `pdflatex` rules before `makeindex`: you don't need those.)

And you should now have the index compiled correctly.

---

If you didn't make the change in the original copy of `makeindex.yaml` (which you should really *not*), then you need to save the new `makeindex.yaml` file in some folder, and then create a `.araraconfig.yaml` file which contains:

```
paths:
- '/path/to/the/folder/'
```

and put this `.araraconfig.yaml` in the current working directory or in your `USER_HOME` folder (see the arara manual, chapter 4 for more on that). If the `makeindex.yaml` file is also in the current working directory you can use `- './'` in the second line of the config file.

---

Full `makeindex.yaml` file:

```
!config
# Arara, the cool TeX automation tool
# Copyright (c) 2018, Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda 
# All rights reserved.
#
# This rule is part of arara.
identifier: nmakeindex
name: MakeIndex
authors:
- Marco Daniel
- Paulo Cereda
commands:
- name: The MakeIndex software
  command: >
    @{
        if (isEmpty(basename))
          { basename = getBasename(file); }
        infile = basename.concat('.').concat(input);
        outfile = [ '-o', basename.concat('.').concat(output) ];
        logfile = [ '-t', basename.concat('.').concat(log) ];
        return getCommand('makeindex', german, style, order, options,
                          logfile, infile, outfile);
    }
arguments:
- identifier: basename
  flag: >
    @{
      parameters.basename
    }
- identifier: input
  flag: >
    @{
      parameters.input
    }
  default: idx
- identifier: output
  flag: >
    @{
      parameters.output
    }
  default: ind
- identifier: log
  flag: >
    @{
      parameters.log
    }
  default: ilg
- identifier: german
  flag: >
    @{
        isTrue(parameters.german, '-g')
    }
- identifier: order
  flag: >
    @{
        if ([ 'letter', 'word' ].contains(parameters.order)) {
            return isTrue(parameters.order == 'letter', '-l', '');
        }
        else {
            throwError('The provided order is invalid.');
        }
    }
- identifier: style
  flag: "@{ [ '-s', parameters.style ] }"
- identifier: options
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.options)) {
            return parameters.options;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of options.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason that `imakeindex` won't work?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Two, actually. First, I didn't know about it (so thanks for mentioning it :-). Second, it seems to have some issue with the `repeatindex` package OP uses: when both packages are loaded the indexes aren't printed. I'll investigate further and update the answer once I find a work around. Anyhow, I mentioned `imakeidx` in the answer.

Comment: And i didn't know about `repeatindex`, so we're even!  (Good luck finding the incompatibility.)

Comment: Re: `imakeindex`: Notice that my example used `memoir`, which had built-in indexing support, for multiple indexes if desired.

Comment: My `memoir` document uses two separate `.bib` files, for two bibliographies. In the "clever", 5-step `arara` sequence, how should one modify the directive `% arara: bibtex if changed (toFile('mybib.bib')) || found ('log', 'Warning: Citation')` (which was spread over 2 lines as shown in the answer) so as to accommodate having two bibliographies?

Comment: @murray `% arara: bibtex if changed (toFile('first_bib.bib')) || changed (toFile('second_bib.bib')) || found ('log', 'Warning: Citation')` should do. This line runs  `bibtex` only when either one of the `.bib` files changed or an undefined citation was spotted by LaTeX. This was originally written for `biber`, which is a bit slower. BibTeX is so fast it's almost not worth the hassle of checking :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: that `bibtex` directive works like a charm, thank you! I had wondered whether there was something similar to the `files` construction of `arara: makeindex: { files: [ first_index, second_index ] } if changed ('idx')`.

Comment: @murray You're welcome! BibTeX already catches multiple `.bib` files in a single run, so the `files` parameter isn't of much use here.