# Is there a way to know that TeX has produced the same PDF?

Tags: compiling

I would like to create a small Python script that will guess the number of compilations needed for one TEX file `myfile.tex`.

Here is my algorithm.

1. Start with a folder containing only `myfile.tex`.
2. Compile `myfile.tex` one 1st time to produce `myfile-v1.pdf`.
3. Compile `myfile.tex` a 2nd time to produce `myfile-v2.pdf` for example.
4. Compare the PDF to look for a change.
5. Go to step 3 as many times as something has changed.

Comment: LaTeX usually tells you that you need to rerun (that's how, for example, `latexmk` knows when to stop).  You can use some `arara` directives to do that ([for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489636/134574)), or you can do it manually by `diff`ing the PDF (make sure that there is no variable data in the pdf; [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440270/134574))

Comment: Thanks for pointing `latexmk`. For `diff`ìng, I will look at your link. :-)

Comment: `arara` looks very intersting!

Comment: It is!  That's what I usually use to build my documents (I'm not a fan of `latexmk`), with a rule set similar to the one in the answer I linked

Comment: Unless you make a big effort, every PDF will always be different (= has a different hash value), since values such as PDF date etc. will always be different. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440270/ for (much) more info.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik What is the problem with `latexmk`?

Comment: @Ingmar The link given by Phelype Oleinik says that we can ask `pdflatex`to avoid that can àf little changes.

Comment: That's the “effort” part, yes. Not really worth it outside of special use cases in my book. YMMV.

Comment: @projetmbc No problem at all!  It's a really nice tool.  I'm just not a big user of it because it is “too clever” for my taste.  It automates the entire build process and I don't like that because I don't have much control of what happens behind the scenes, and I personally don't like that and I prefer the kind of control that `arara` gives.  But if you just want to build the document without worries, `latexmk` is really good!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik For me the killer feature in latexmk is the continuous preview mode which I use constantly. Then I just have to save and everything is done. Mind, though that much of my latex work nowadays is editing other people's stuff

Comment: @daleif Can you explain the continuous preview mode?

Comment: Latexmk goes into a loop after the compilation and keeps a look on all the files used by the project, then recompile if one changes. I generally combine it with a feature to stop compilation on first error. You loose the error parsing in the editor, but I can live with that

Comment: @daleif I keep that in my mind to be more efficient. Thanks for sharing!