# Bigfoot and a "! Missing number, treated as zero." error

Tags: bigfoot

### The problem

After updating `MiKTeX` (`MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit`) and `Texmaker` (two clean re-installations after several issues I had with obsolete packages), my tex file wouldn't compile properly anymore, especially regarding my different levels of footnotes. Two errors emerged and my output would be fulled of added `=`.

I identified the problem as coming from the `bigfoot` package. I was previously using `bigfoot` in explicit combination with `manyfoot` and `perpage` and it was working fine. I soon discovered it was better to use `bigfoot` alone (as it relies on `manyfoot` and `perpage` anyway). But the errors occured in both case in the exact same way.

The two errors are the following and they emerge at each footnote:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               =
l.12 \footnote{
           A numbered footnote.}
?
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
               =
l.12 \footnote{
           A numbered footnote.}
?
```

The result being each footnote mark (in the text) to be followed by a `=` sign. Plus, another `=` sign is added at the begining of every page except the first one.

I checked online (notably on Overleaf) for what seems to be a very common error but no case instructed seems to be relevant to my problem. For the first error, I checked [here](https://fr.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Missing_number,_treated_as_zero#Common_Causes), and [here](https://fr.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Illegal_unit_of_measure_(pt_inserted)) for the second one. The [TeXfaq](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nonum) also mentionned a problem when upgrading from a `LaTeX 2.9` but it was not the case here.

### M(N)WE

Here is a **MWE**:

```
% xelatex
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{B}[alph]
\DeclareNewFootnote[plain]{C}[fnsymbol]

\begin{document}

\footnote{A numbered footnote.}
\footnoteB{An alphabetical footnote.}
\footnoteC{A footnote with symbols.}

\clearpage

\footnote{A second numbered footnote.}

\end{document}
```

### Logfile and filelist

The **logfile**:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.7.21)  26 JUL 2019 22:09
entering extended mode
**./mwe2.tex
(mwe2.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/bigfoot\bigfoot.sty"
Package: bigfoot 2015/08/30 2.1 makes footnotes work
(C:\Users\Erizo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/manyfoot\manyfoot.sty
Package: manyfoot 2005/09/11 v1.10 Many Footnote Levels Package (NCC)

(C:\Users\Erizo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/nccfoots\nccfoots.sty
Package: nccfoots 2005/02/03 v1.2 NCC Footnotes Package (NCC)
)
\MFL@columnwidth=\dimen103
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/bigfoot\suffix.sty"
Package: suffix 2006/07/15 1.5a Variant command support
)
(C:\Users\Erizo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/perpage\perpage.sty
Package: perpage 2006/07/15 1.12 Reset/sort counters per page
\c@abspage=\count88
)
\footnotewidowpenalty=\count89
\footnoteclubpenalty=\count90
\finalfootnotewidowpenalty=\count91
\c@FN@totalid=\count92
\c@pp@a@FN@totalid=\count93
\FN@id=\count94
\FN@master=\marks1
\FN@slave=\marks2
\FN@color=\marks3
\FN@outervsize=\dimen104
\FN@vsize=\skip43
\FN@insertions=\box27
\FN@output=\toks14
\FN@tempbox=\box28
\FN@savebox=\insert199
\FN@topmarkbox=\box29
\FN@outputflag=\count95
\FN@myvsize=\dimen105
\bigfoottolerance=\count96
)
\footinsdefault=\insert198
\c@footnotedefault=\count97
\footinsB=\insert197
\c@footnoteB=\count98
\footinsC=\insert196
\c@footnoteC=\count99

(mwe2.aux)
\openout1 = `mwe2.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
\FN@cache198=\box30
\FN@cache197=\box31
\FN@cache196=\box32
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 12.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   =
l.12 \footnote{
               A numbered footnote.}
? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   =
l.12 \footnote{
               A numbered footnote.}
?
```

The **filelist**:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 bigfoot.sty    2015/08/30 2.1 makes footnotes work
manyfoot.sty    2005/09/11 v1.10 Many Footnote Levels Package (NCC)
nccfoots.sty    2005/02/03 v1.2 NCC Footnotes Package (NCC)
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5a Variant command support
 perpage.sty    2006/07/15 1.12 Reset/sort counters per page
```

Any idea of how I could solve that problem?

Comment: I don't seem to get any error with TeXLive 2019 using Kile. `*File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 bigfoot.sty    2015/08/30 2.1 makes footnotes work
manyfoot.sty    2005/09/11 v1.10 Many Footnote Levels Package (NCC)
nccfoots.sty    2005/02/03 v1.2 NCC Footnotes Package (NCC)
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5a Variant command support
 perpage.sty    2014/10/25 2.0 Reset/sort counters per page
  omscmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********`

Comment: you have very old files perpage should be 2014 for example I get this filelist `*File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 bigfoot.sty    2015/08/30 2.1 makes footnotes work
manyfoot.sty    2005/09/11 v1.10 Many Footnote Levels Package (NCC)
nccfoots.sty    2005/02/03 v1.2 NCC Footnotes Package (NCC)
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5a Variant command support
 perpage.sty    2014/10/25 2.0 Reset/sort counters per page
 ***********`

Comment: note your packages come from two different trees, the old perpage one comes from your folder, so this is the standard miktex FAQ, you need to update both user and admin versions in the miktex console.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29616/what-is-the-preferable-setup-for-miktex-to-keep-all-packages-up-to-date-easily

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your were right. The problem came from Texmaker calling old packages from the personnal MiKTeX tree. I will now pay very careful attention to that point when installing new pakages. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you @azetina for setting me on the track of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As David Carlisle mentionned it in a comment, the problem came from Texmaker calling and using old packages installed into the *personnal* *user* MiKTeX tree (`C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\...`) and not the one installed into the *admin* MiKTeX tree (`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\...`) as I expected. The later one being the one up-to-date.

In this specific case, related to using the `bigfoot` package, three `sty` files were called from the personnal user MiKTeX tree. The problem is that some old semi-independant packages (`perpage` and `bigfoot` for example) were also integrated into a renewed one since then (the new `bigfoot`) so the `sty` files are not disposed into the same files anymore. So the previous situation:

- `manyfoot.sty` called from the independant package `manyfoot` in the *personnal user* MiKTeX tree. This file is now part of the `ncctools` bundle.
- `nccfoots.sty` called from the independant package `nccfoots` in the *personnal user* MiKTeX tree. This file is now part of the `ncctools` bundle too.
- `perpage.sty` called from the independant package `perpage` in the *personnal user* MiKTeX tree. This file is now part of the `bigfoot` package.

### Solution

- In the **personal user** MiKTeX tree, delete manually the files of the old versions of `bigfoot`, `manyfoot`, `nccfoots` and `perpage` (they all are in `C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\`).
- Open the **MiKTeX (admin) console**, (re)install the following packages: `bigfoot` and `ncctools`.
- In the **MiKTeX (admin) console**, refresh the `file name database` (FNDB).
- Now, open the **MiKTeX (user) console** and refresh its `file name database` (FNDB) too.

Your compilation should now run smoothly.