# Broken installation because of iftex

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

After updating packages (on Miktex), almost nothing compiles anymore. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
plop
\end{document}
```

results in the following errors:

```
C:\Users\TL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty:10: Undefined control sequence. [\ifxetex]
C:\Users\TL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty:12: Extra \else. [\else]
C:\Users\TL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty:12: Undefined control sequence. [\else\ifluatex]
C:\Users\TL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty:14: Extra \else. [\else]
C:\Users\TL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty:16: Extra \fi. [\fi]
C:\Users\TL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty:16: Extra \fi. [\fi\fi]
C:\Users\TL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty:289: Undefined control sequence. [  \defaultfontfeatures]
C:\Users\TL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty:290: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [     L]
C:\Users\TL\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\libertine\libertine.sty:296: Undefined control sequence. [    \setmainfont]
```

However, the package **iftex** is installed, and there is no **ifxetex** package to download. Seems like **ifptex** provides `\ifXeTeX`, not `ifxetex` (seriously !?!...). Similar problems arise for `\ifluatex`.

How to fix this ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `iftex` package was updated a few months (weeks?) ago, and now both `ifxetex` and `ifluatex` (and a couple others) just load `iftex`. I'd guess that you updated the `ifxetex` package but not `iftex`. Check that, and also “make sure you update in both _user_ and _admin_ modes”

Comment: WTF... it works now, that discrepency between user and admin modes is pretty bad (usually I do everything as admin, I had no idea some packages were installed as user and thus not updated). Thank you anyway !

Comment: You're welcome! I don't have MiKTeX (and avoid Windows), so I don't really know the whys and hows, but [“update in user and admin mode”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=update+in+user+and+admin+mode) seems to solve several MiKTeX problems :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by updating (both in user and admin mode)

Comment: Agree, it is just sad this very important information is so hard to get (as is it really non-intuitive...)

Comment: I  have the same problem, but this solution didn't work for me (I installed for all users). My solution consisted in making a copy of the `iftex` directory in `LocalTeXMF/tex/latex` (the distribution installs it in `tex/generic`).

Comment: @Synxis [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67713/134574) seems to explains why this user/admin problem arises, and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29630/134574) suggests installing with user rights only (if I got it right).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik While it's true, you don't get to these answers by searching for errors similar to what is in my question...