# Moving MiKTeX package to admin directory

Tags: packages, miktex

I have a MiKTeX installation which I use for several users. I had MiKTeX set up to install packages on the fly as needed, which is probably the reason why some packages are installed "by user" and others are installed "by admin". (I have now changed the setting so that now I think the packages will be installed on the fly "by admin", see [this relevant thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32635/40862).)

As I understand it, the packages installed "by user" are not directly available to other users, so I probably have multiple copies of the same package for different users, which uses extra space, and also is likely the reason why I get out of sync warnings rather often.

1. Is there an easy way of migrating packages from user to admin?
2. If I install as admin a package that is installed by user, how can I get rid of the user copy of the package?

Comment: well the users will have to deinstall the packages. But installation on-the-fly as admin will only work if the users have the admin password to allow the installation. If this is not the case the best is probably to install all packages as admin to avoid that the user on-the-fly is ever triggered.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, but I don't really know which packages I'm going to need in advance. And how do I do it quickly? Installing the packages one-by-one is going to be pretty annoying when I've got dozens of them.

Comment: well 10 years ago I used on-the-fly too, but nowadays I simply install everything and then check regularly for new packages and install them too.